# How do I determine current value of a used bicycle?

Tags: mountain-bike, used-bike, price

I'm looking at purchasing a bike from a private seller. I know the price of the bike when it was brand new and the bike appears to be in almost new condition and contains all original equipment.

How do I determine what a good price for a bike might be, given its age and condition? Is there a website I can go to that lists used bike prices?

Comment: yeah, eBay. I have a constant search on there (not for a bike I want to buy, but in the vain hope that one I had nicked one day will turn up) and its a good place to see (a) peoples' expectations and (b) reality

Comment: Be wary of people who include the value of newer components. Lots of people think that if they upgrade to a $60 derailleur that they can boost it to $100 more than the expected price. (Junk like kickstands, bar tape, bottle cages, headlights, racks...unless it is high quality gear, don't pay more for it.)

Comment: Keep in mind that a $1200 (list) bike will sell for $800 new at end of season.

Comment: This is a great question with lots of upvotes @Batman,andy256, freiheit. Can we edit it to keep it open?

Comment: $800 is high  http://www.bicyclebluebook.com/SearchListingDetail.aspx?id=3047492&make=750&model=75913&year=2013&priceMax=20000  No a shop does not just slash prices by 1/3 at the end of season to clear inventory.   They don't even have a 1/3 margin.  It does not take 1/3 cut to get people to buy last years bike - it is more like 10% and maybe 20% if there are was a significant design or component change.

Comment: I think leave it closed - the question was asked in 2013 about a 2012 bike's price.  Its no longer relevant in late 2015.

Comment: I tried to edit it so that it is more generic and could be used as a reference question for other "what is the price" questions.

Comment: @RoboKaren Excellent -- I'd vote to reopen if I had the rep. It's also good that both answers were addressing the general question and completely ignore the details of the specific bike that you edited out of the question.

Answer (score 10):

eBay is a good tool for determining value, search for your item selecting closed auctions and you often get a list of your item, bike in this case that has already sold (or not).  The price of those transactions helps me determine relative value.

Likewise craigslist shows you another view of what people are asking.  If your target bike is being listed for less or more than your deal, you have more information.  Sometimes you have to search outside your area to get a few hits, especially if your target bike is popular and scarce.

Some other things to consider, is the person a 'dealer or private person who sells a lot of bikes'? Or, is it a person selling their own or a friend's bike? If possible, take the bike to your bike shop/mechanic and have them look it over.  Just because it shifts right today does not mean the drive train is not worn out.  Example, my Trek Nav looks like new, rides like a dream, but has 1500 miles on it and I'm pretty sure it needs a chain, cassette and who knows what else.

Good luck!

Comment: This is exactly the way I've priced everything I've ever bought or sold!

Answer (score 3):

I believe that half the retail value of the bicycle is a good "rule of thumb" for a bike that is not more than 1-2 years old. A lot of new bikes are sold at great discounts (30% is not unusual) and this pushes the prices of used bikes down. The technology improves each year as well, and new models might be released at even lower price points than the previous models, but with better frames and equipment.

Here is an example in [bicyclebook](http://www.bicyclebluebook.com/searchlistingdetail.aspx?id=3041326).

Comment: And making sure you have the right model makes a difference too, example a Trek Nav 1.0 is very different than a 3.0 and their old model numbers 100 - 300 add yet another level of complexity.